# Criteria for the area bounded to be minimum

Tags: calculus, area

The area bounded by $y=e^x,2y+2k-2kx-1-e^2=0$ is minimum for what value of $k$.

The second equation is the equation of a line but i find it tedious to find out the points of intersection.

Any way to solve this problem in a short method.thanks.

Comment: So, you would rather that someone else do the tedious work for you, and quickly as well?

Comment: @copper.hat no i meant if someone could suggest an alternative method.quick one because it came in an exination with very little time to spend for a question.